# Disabling checkbox in IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have two checkboxes in a form and if the first checkbox is checked, the second should be enabled, and if the first is unchecked the second should be disabled. I made a quick function to handle this:

```
function toggleElement(sender, receiver)
{
    var sendEl = document.getElementById(sender);
    var recEl = document.getElementById(receiver);
    if (sendEl.checked)
        recEl.disabled = false;
    else
        recEl.disabled = 'disabled';
}
```

This works fine in FF and IE 8/9 but doesn't do anything in IE7, I added the following to see what was happening:

```
alert(receiver);
alert(recEl);
alert(recEl.disabled);
```

In the browsers that work (FF, IE8+) these alert 'name', '[object]', and 'true' if disabled 'false' if not. In IE7 the alerts are fired but say 'name', '[object]', and 'true' even though the checkbox is never disabled (it does not get greyed out and I can continue to click it)

Any ideas why it isn't working in IE7?

Comment: It was true to begin with, but another forum suggested changing to 'disabled' to match the examples on w3schools

Comment: It appears as if sendEl.checked is always false in IE7, which makes less sense because that makes me expect that the second checkbox is always disabled, unless the issue is with the document.getElementById in IE7

Comment: Maybe we'll need more context, because [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37xwS/) that works (at least on IE9-as-7), even *with* the `disabled = "disabled"` stuff. EDIT: When I checked it on IETester-as-7, it looked like there was a delay in updating the visual look of the second checkbox. Can you confirm that IE7 really isn't disabling it? Could it be that it just isn't changing the looks?

Comment: I don't have an IE on my machine, but if setting it to `false` does not work, you might try with `element.removeAttribute("disabled")` or `delete element.disabled`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're manipulating the DOM, the `disabled` property should be set to `true` or `false`, not a string. What happens if you replace `'disabled'` with `true`?

Also you might simplify the logic to

```
recEl.disabled = !sendEl.checked;
```

This is very basic stuff in JavaScript; even IE shouldn't be having a problem with it.

Comment: 'disabled' like any string is a truthy value... - not correct, but should still work

Comment: Still not sure what caused the problem to begin with, but working from this and changing to JQuery seems to have fixed the problem, final code became: 
function toggleElement(sender, receiver)
{
$("#"+receiver).attr('disabled', !($("#"+sender).attr('checked')));
}

Answer (score 1):

`disabled` is a boolean attribute. Use `false` and `true`, instead of `false` and `"disabled"`. It should work.

Thw whole `disabled="disabled"` thing in HTML markup was because of **XHTML** validators, not because the value is allowed to be the string "disabled". Actually, if you apply this pattern to the HTML5 `required` attribute, you'll get required fields even if you say `required="false"`. The way to do it in HTML5 markup is to specify `required` when `true`, and not specify it at all when `false`.

Comment: I originally had it set to true, but changed it to 'disabled' at the request of another forum, citing w3schools example of the attribute

Comment: That's cargo cult programming. I added an explanation as to why someone would advise for such a thing. Nowadays it's wrong to do that.

Comment: Please see http://w3fools.com/ as to why you should not take what they say as gospel